# Azure Database export with C#

Tags: c#, azure

My C# programme works with Azure Database.

I'm using Microsoft.Rest and Microsoft.Azure.Management libraries to do some stuff (DB copy, manipulate, delete, etc...).

I try to do an export of an Azure DB, but I can't find how to do that in C#.
Does anyone know how I can do that, or direct me to an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution of my problem:
I had to update my Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql library.
Now, I can use this export method:

> public static ImportExportResponse Export(this IDatabasesOperations
>   operations, string resourceGroupName, string serverName, string
>   databaseName, ExportRequest parameters);

Comment: So this exports the DB to a local file as a .bacpac ?

Comment: No, mmcrae, the backup DB is in the cloud, not local.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my understanding, you are talking about Azure SQL database. I assumed that you could [Export your Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export).

> I try to do an export of an Azure DB, but I can't find how to do that in C#.

According to your description, I checked [Microsoft Azure Management Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/) and found you could refer to the following code snippet for exporting your azure sql database into the azure blob storage:

```
CertificateCloudCredentials credential = new CertificateCloudCredentials("{subscriptionId}","{managementCertificate}");
var sqlManagement = new SqlManagementClient(credential);
var result = sqlManagement.Dac.Export("{serverName}", new DacExportParameters()
{
    BlobCredentials = new DacExportParameters.BlobCredentialsParameter()
    {
        StorageAccessKey = "{storage-account-accesskey}",
        Uri = new Uri("https://{storage-accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}")
    },
    ConnectionInfo = new DacExportParameters.ConnectionInfoParameter()
    {
        DatabaseName = "{dbname}",
        ServerName = "{serverName}.database.windows.net",
        UserName = "{username}",
        Password = "{password}"
    }
});
```

And you could use `sqlManagement.Dac.GetStatus` for retrieving the status of the export operation.

Additionally, the Microsoft Azure Management Libraries uses [Export Database (classic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781282.aspx), for newer resource manager based REST API, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export#Databases_Export). Moreover, you could refer to [create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account#create-a-storage-account) and leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) for a simple way to manage your storage resources, for more details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs).

Comment: Thanks Bruce, it's exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, this code is too old, the classes / methods are no more in the new versions of the Azure.Management libraries.
But I've found the solution of the problem.