# How to export azure database to blob storage

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I need to know exactly how to login to Azure, using c#.

I basically want to do this, but from the code: 
]a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)

Here is the code I copied from the internet trying to achieve this: 
But I don't know how to generate the token.

```
                SqlManagementClient managementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));

        var exportParams = new DacExportParameters()
        {
            BlobCredentials = new DacExportParameters.BlobCredentialsParameter()
            {
                StorageAccessKey = storageKey,
                Uri = new Uri(baseStorageUri)
            },
            ConnectionInfo = new DacExportParameters.ConnectionInfoParameter()
            {
                ServerName = azureSqlServer,
                DatabaseName = azureSqlDatabase,
                UserName = adminLogin,
                Password = adminPassword
            }
        };
        var exportResult = managementClient.Dac.Export(azureSqlServerName, exportParams);
```

I have a GetToken function, but I have no idea where to take the 
tenant + client id + secret

```
  private static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string 
          clientId, string secretKey)
        {
               var authenticationContext = new 

             AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
                   var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
                  var result =authenticationContext
                 .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
            credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        var token = result.Result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
```

This question was asked before
[Azure Database export with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033940/azure-database-export-with-c-sharp/48581974#48581974)
but I need to see the actual code and explanation on how to get the connection info.

Comment: But your code shows you where tenantID, clientID and secretkey go..

Comment: yeah .. My code is complete, but I have no idea where to take the tenantId, clientId + secretKey, nor what these actually mean. So I have a door I don't know how to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to see the actual code and explanation on how to get the connection info.

I would recommend you follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) about registering your AAD application and adding the secret key. Moreover, you could also follow [Using the Azure ARM REST API – Get Access Token](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

> SqlManagementClient managementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));

Based on your code, I assumed that you are using the package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql/), if you use the `TokenCloudCredentials`, you may receive the following error response:

[image]

AFAIK, [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/) requires the X509Certificate2 authentication, you need to construct the `CertificateCloudCredentials` for your `SqlManagementClient`. For uploading a management certificate under your subscription, you could follow [Upload an Azure Service Management Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-api-management-certs). For retrieving the `X509Certificate2` instance, you could follow the code snippet under the Authenticate using a management certificate section from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx).

For token-based authentication, you could use the package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/) and construct your `SqlManagementClient` as follows:

```
var sqlManagement = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCredentials("{access-token}"));
```

Moreover, you need to change the resource from `https://management.core.windows.net/` to `https://management.azure.com/` when invoking the `AcquireTokenAsync` method.